# Mac Caffe CUDA driver issue

Tags: python, macos, cuda, wrapper, caffe

I'm trying to build caffe with the python wrapper on Mac OSX 10.0, but keep getting the following error when I execute the command: make runtest (make all -j8 and make test work fine).

> Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (35 vs. 0) CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version

I have updated the CUDA driver to the latest version online. I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling CUDA and the driver, but the error still persists. How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you gone through the [mac getting started guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-mac-os-x/index.html#abstract), and validated your CUDA install?  For example, are you able to build and run CUDA samples codes?  Which actual CUDA version do you have installed?  Which actual driver version do you have installed?  What GPU is in your Mac?

Comment: I just tried to build the CUDA sample codes. All worked fine, but when running devicequery I got the exact same error as my original post. I have 7.0 installed, the driver version is 7.0.3.6, and my GPU is AMD Radeon R9 M290X 2048 MB

Comment: You can't run CUDA on a AMD Radeon GPU.  You may want to switch to another machine or else configure/build a version of Caffe that doesn't depend on CUDA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was teased out in the comments, the basic problem here is an attempt to use CUDA on a GPU that does not support it (AMD Radeon ...).

[CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cuda/info) is a GPU programming technology that only runs on NVIDIA GPUs (ignoring emulators and the like.)

To make forward progress, some possibilities might be:

1. Switch to another machine that has an NVIDIA GPU.
2. Modify the configuration of Caffe so that it does not use or depend on CUDA.